# Causes of hand lesions

Tags: dermatology

What are causes of slowly growing (over 1-2 months) solitary lesions on finger with slightly raised and red margin and dry crusty centre?

Answer (score 1):

Is wart (you need to see doctor). This can be most urgent.

The treatment is burned with nitrogen.

http://www.webmd.com/skin-problems-and-treatments/cryotherapy-for-warts

> **Remove warts:** If you don’t want to go to the doctor to treat your
>   wart, try lemon juice as a do-it-yourself option. Dabbing lemon juice
>   on the wart will break it down and it should disappear in two weeks.

**Source :** http://uk.businessinsider.com/things-you-can-do-with-lemon-peels-juice-2015-4?r=US&IR=T

**Be careful :**

You can pass on the infection to you friend/familly. Please, treat it quickly.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Health.SE. Can you add more ifnormation on why you think it's a wart, and specifically one that can be treated with nitrogen? Also, I can't tell how does your last link relates to that, can you add some context? Thanks!

Comment: 'dry crusty centre' is specific at the wart, the wart are generally on the hand or the foot is transmitted with touch with the skin or with an object. See on google image : https://contourderm.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/wart-web-2-669x272.jpg
The last link is source of quote block.

Comment: aah, now I feel stupid about that last link ;-) don't know why I didn't get that...

Comment: Do not assume it is mine. It disappeared rapidly with steroid+salicylic acid cream.